# Holomorphic Eisenstein Series

Tags: modular-forms

$$G_k (z)=\sum_{\displaystyle(m,n) \neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(mz+n)^k}$$

For $k \geq 3$ how to show that $G_k (z)=0$ for odd $k$ and

$G_k (\tau z)=(cz+d)^k G_k (z)$ for $\tau \in SL_2(Z), \tau =  \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b \\
c & d \\ \end{array} \right) $

$(m,n)$ are integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For odd values of $k$, you can see that if you expand the sum, you'll get cancellations of terms because $m$ and $n$ run through $\mathbb{Z}$ and you have negative values to an odd power and also positive values to an odd power. For the second part:

$$G_k (\tau z)=\sum_{\displaystyle(m,n) \neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(m(\tau z)+n)^k}$$
$$=\sum_{\displaystyle(m,n) \neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(m(\frac{az+b}{cz+d})+n)^k}$$
$$=\sum_{\displaystyle(m,n) \neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{cz+d})^{-k}(m(az+b)+n(cz+d))^k}$$
$$=(cz+d)^k\sum_{\displaystyle(m,n) \neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{((ma+nc)z+(mb+nd))^k}$$ 
But $m$ and $n$ $\in\mathbb{Z}$ run through all of $\mathbb{Z}$ so :
$$G_k (\tau z)=(cz+d)^k\sum_{\displaystyle(m',n') \neq (0,0)} \frac{1}{(m'z+n')^k}=(cz+d)^k G_k (z)$$
Where $m'=ma+nc$ and $n'=mb+nd$.

Comment: Not only does $(m,n)$ run through all of $\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{(0,0)\}$, but its mapping to $(m',n')$ is a member of $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z})$ and therefore one-to-one. This is the justification for the last step.